# Spring MongoDB Could not instantiate Map type: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring boot with RabbitMQ and MongoDB. I have a dead letter queue set up which saves my DeadLetterMessage in Mongo. When I want to retrieve those messages from the database to re enqueue them, I get the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'zvbMohmApiApplication': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [be.cm.apps.evsb.zvb.api.mohm.ZvbMohmApiApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6d1f64e]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Map type: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at be.cm.apps.evsb.zvb.api.mohm.ZvbMohmApiApplication.main(ZvbMohmApiApplication.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [be.cm.apps.evsb.zvb.api.mohm.ZvbMohmApiApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6d1f64e]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Map type: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Map type: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders
at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createMap(CollectionFactory.java:326) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:1083) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:225) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1491) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1389) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:378) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:295) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:275) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:245) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:194) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:190) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3017) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2626) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2353) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:843) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findById(SimpleMongoRepository.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at be.cm.apps.evsb.zvb.api.mohm.ZvbMohmApiApplication.<init>(ZvbMohmApiApplication.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
at be.cm.apps.evsb.zvb.api.mohm.ZvbMohmApiApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6d1f64e.<init>(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createMap(CollectionFactory.java:323) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 64 common frames omitted
```

My DeadLetterMessage class looks like this:

```
import be.cm.apps.evsb.zvb.core.entity.BaseEntity;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;

@Document(collection = "deadLetters")
public class DeadLetterMessage extends BaseEntity implements Message {

    private MessageHeaders messageHeaders;
    private Object payload;

    public DeadLetterMessage(final Object payload, final MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
        this.messageHeaders = messageHeaders;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public DeadLetterMessage() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageHeaders getHeaders() {
        return messageHeaders;
    }
}
```

One solution to my problem would be to keep a Map in my DeadLetterMessage and just set it with the contents of MessageHeaders, but I wanted to see if it was possible with my current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration uses 2 techniques for this problem.

The [`ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mongodb/store/ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore.java#L42) serializes the message (which requires that all payload and header values implement `Serializable`).

The [`MongoDbMessageStore`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mongodb/store/MongoDbMessageStore.java#L100) uses custom converters.